# Missing Certificate template From certificate to issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, certificate, ad-certificate-services, templates

I have following problem:
Environement:

- SERVER 2008 STANDARD EDITION
- ACTIVE DOMAIN SERVICIES INSTALLED
- ACTICE CERTIFICATE SERVICIES INSTALLED
- ENTERPRISE CA INSTALLED

I create a duplicate of certificate Template without problem.
I would like to ad it to the Certificate Templates of my CA but when I try to do ad it with Certificate to issue the duplicate certificate dont appear in the choosing list.
I check the all authorisation and its appeare well.
Some body can help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Solution: Upgrade your Windows Server edition to Enterprise or Datacenter.

Root Cause: Standard edition only supports a small subset of templates, making it a poor choice for an enterprise CA.  In my opinion Microsoft should have left it out of Standard Edition, as most people need custom templates and don't realize this limitation until they are in a tough spot like you.
http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/certificates/creating-a-new-certificate-template-in-windows-server-2003-standard-edition.aspx