# Issuing Computer Certificates to Non-Domain Members (Enterprise CA)

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, certificate-authority, microsoft-ftmg-2010, ad-certificate-services

I am trying to implement remote client access using L2TP/IPSec VPN for both domain members and non-members. Domain members is fine and working OK but I am having trouble issuing a certificate to the non-domain members.

I believe I must be looking at issuing the computer certs via web enrollment, so I have made a duplicate of the Computer template, and changed the Subject Name setting to 'Supply in the request', since I assuming trying to build it from AD is pointless for a non-member.

Problem is, when I try to create a New > 'Certificate Template to Issue', my new template is not showing in the list, nor is the template showing in the web enrollment site.

I have a feeling I am missing something simple. I am using an Enterprise Admin account when using the CA MMC, and my Enterprise CA is running on a Server 2003 R2 Std machine.

Any suggestions to what I might be missing/doing wrong? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Actually just dug a bit further and found that this is a limitation of 2003 *Std*.

See Link : http://serverfault.com/questions/252544/missing-certificate-template-from-certificate-to-issue

Back to the drawing board then :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The New > Cert to Issue thing, you just have to wait 5 minutes for AD to catch up.

You are correct that you can't issue certs that are based on AD information to non-AD members. You can use the Web Interface, CA Management Console, `certutil`, or PowerShell to process the CSRs.

Note: The above requires Enterprise or DC versions of Windows Server. Standard or SBS will not work.

Comment: Thanks Chris. You have confirmed what I feared - standard edition being a no-go. Looks like I'll have go an ask for money to buy an enterprise licence :(